# Error: export 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver' (imported as 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser'

Tags: angular, angular-animations

After upgrading my Angular from 12.0.2 to 13.0.3 everything was working fine. I was trying to remove some packages that was not used such as `jquery`, and some other i do not remember etc. and after that I deleted `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` to installed all packages again. After that I recieved bunch of errors which then i again reverted package.json and tried npm i then I am getting below errors. And I am unable to fixed it.

Any idea how can i resolve this ?

```
./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2020/animations.mjs:531:9-31 - Error: export 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations' (imported as 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2020/animations.mjs:531:69-88 - Error: export 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver' (imported as 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)
```

package.json

```
"private": true,
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "13.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "highlight.js": "10.7.2",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "rrule": "2.6.8",
    "rxjs": "7.1.0",
    "tslib": "2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngx-builders/analyze": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/highlight.js": "9.12.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.4",
    "@types/node": "15.0.1",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^6.0.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "2.1.2",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~4.4.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.5",
    "ws": "^8.2.2",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.1"
  }
}
```

---

I see that the issue is with

`@angular/animations` package.

When I remove that and manually add that package from my old [backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYZ3307v4t3_obYHv1BRuub_h1E6_828/view?usp=sharing) it works fine.

`ng-project/node_modules/@angular/animations`

I replace this folder completely from my backup and it worked without re-compile.

Again if I run `npm install`it will not work. Help me here to understand.

Comment: Have you recently updated your angular version?

Comment: Yes I did. it was from 12 to 13.0.3. After upgrading everything was working very fine. the issue arries only after I start removing package and delete node_modules and re-install packages. Now even if I revert my package json to prevous commit it still shows that issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue with my project. Did you find any solution to this error?

Comment: No but I have manage to fixed it by uploading backup of `@angular/animation` folder. I have added in description.

Comment: Check my answer may be no need to use or upload old backup and just to use or downgrade the animation package version to 13.2.0 or lower will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I researched a lot and did not find a solution to this issue as it's occurring only on the newer version of the animation package.

I tried the below versions:

- 13.2.4 (Latest one) throwing same es error
- 13.2.3 throwing same es error
- 13.2.2 throwing same es error
- 13.2.1 throwing same es error
- **13.2.0 working without error.**

So I think for a temporary fix you should update your `package.json` by pointing to a specific version of this `npm` like below.

```
"@angular/animations": "13.2.0"
```

this or lower version will not throw any error and all newer versions have the `ɵsupportsWebAnimations` issue.

Ref of issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45191

**Edit:**

If anyone wants a proper solution and wants the latest version of `@angular/animations` then they need to be the exact same version as the other **Angular framework packages** by doing `ng update` so once all the core Angular framework packages match with the same version you will no longer see the above error and can build your app without error.

Comment: But I have 13.0.3. How comes its throwing error for me. Is it feasible If i update angular animation version to `13.2.0` and rest other to `13.0.3` ?

Comment: Your solution works fine. Even If i am at angular 13.0.3. I have updated only `@angular/animation` to `13.2.0`. The error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and I tried all possible solutions out there but didn't work.

Then I changed

`"@angular/animations": "^13.0.2",`
to
`"@angular/animations": "~13.0.2",` in my `package.json` file

and my `npm i` worked.